# looped count query(oracle)

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to recieve the number of rows for each day.
Example:
For one day I will count number of rows like that:

```
select count(*) from stat.jurnal where dt like '%14.09.07'
```

Instead of %14.09.07 I have an array(@arrayDates) of dates in such format.

So I have

```
19781   13.09.07
18645   14.09.07
21641   14.09.07
21641   14.09.07
21641   14.09.07
10829   15.09.07
 9088   15.09.07
55512   15.09.07
```

What I want to recieve after query:

```
1
4
4
```

Comment: That's probably not what you want to receive, because there is no way to tell which date is which.

Comment: Could you add the DDL statement for stat.jurnal, please? (It looks like dt is a string column)

Comment: Why the "LIKE"? Is there data with "extra junk" in front of the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming dt is a DATE column, you can group by the date part with TRUNC:

```
select trunc(dt) as dt, count(*) as cnt
from stat.jurnal 
group by trunc(dt);
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, I'd humbly suggest you accept it :-)

Comment: Sorry, I did't know that I should do that.